# Delay in for loop for Simon game

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, delay

I am new to React, so I am probably not using best practices. I am trying to build this "Simon Says" game, but I am stuck trying to put delay in between each of my `for` loops, they run at the same time. I've looked at other solutions for this but they don't seem to fit with mine. I've also tried using `setTimeout` but that just plays all the animations at once after the delay. This is the `for` loop and the functions i want to have a delay in between:

```
  newRound() {
    this.setState({
        pcSequence: this.state.pcSequence.concat(
          Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1)
      },() => {
        this.state.pcSequence.forEach(element =>
          this.startAnimations(element)
        );
      }
    );
  }

  startAnimations(element) {
    if (element == 1) {
      this.activeBtn1(0);
    } else if (element == 2) {
      this.activeBtn2(1);
    } else if (element == 3) {
      this.activeBtn3(2);
    } else if (element == 4) {
      this.activeBtn4(3);
    }
  }
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found help elsewhere and wanted to show what I did in case anyone else ever comes along looking for something similar. I removed the `for` loop and used `map`:

```
  newRound() {
    this.setState({
        pcSequence: this.state.pcSequence.concat(
          Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1),
          round: this.state.round + 1
      },() => {
        this.state.pcSequence.map((element,index)=> {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.startAnimations(element);
          }, index * 1000);
        })
      }
    );
  }

  startAnimations(element) {

      if (element == 1) {
        this.activeBtn1(0);
      } else if (element == 2) {
        this.activeBtn2(1);
      } else if (element == 3) {
        this.activeBtn3(2);
      } else if (element == 4) {
        this.activeBtn4(3);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I like your question and manage to get it working, i will share code below:

```
state = {
    pcSequence: [],
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.newRound();
  }

  newRound() {
    this.setState({
        pcSequence: [1,4,3,2]
      },() => this.startSequence()
    );
  }

  startSequence() {
    if (this.state.pcSequence.length > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.startAnimations(this.state.pcSequence.pop());
        this.startSequence();
      }, 1000) // 1000ms === 1 second
    }
  }

  startAnimations(element) {
    if (element === 1) {
      console.log('element 1', element)
    } else if (element === 2) {
      console.log('element 2', element)
    } else if (element === 3) {
      console.log('element 3', element)
    } else if (element === 4) {
      console.log('element 4', element)
    }
  }
```

you can call this.newRound each time you want to reset buttons and also fill the array in a better way, yours is only filling the array with 1 item not 4 like [1] or [4]

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply! it all works for me except that the pcSequence.pop() is deleting the numbers out of my pcSequence state, i need the pattern to be the same until they win or quit with one random number 1-4 being added to the array  each round and all the animations play again plus the new one.